# How do I know what a faction's relationship with me is?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, how do I know what faction I have a relationship with? I was a Knight in the Brotherhood ,

> and had Paladin Danse as a companion,

but when I attacked a place, all the sudden the Brotherhood became enemies. Why did that happen and is there a way to check the faction's relationship with me?

Edit: Replaying the battle, the Brotherhood of Steel no longer attacked me.

Comment: You can use ">!" to denote a spoiler line. Just make sure the question makes sense without the spoiler text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faction relationships in Fallout 4 are entirely binary. Either they will want to kill you on sight, or they're friendly towards you.

The only factions with which this status can really *change* are the Minutemen, the Railroad, the Brotherhood, and the Institute. It's generally pretty obvious when it does, as faction members will kill you on sight. Attacking members of the faction while they are friendly is a pretty good way to change that status. Unfortunately, this can sometimes include hitting them with a stray bullet during a chaotic firefight.

Comment: I've shot down 2 BOS Vertibirds while hidden and sneaking, and the BOS is still friendly towards me. So if you *have* to kill members of either faction, at least make sure nobody sees you doing it. (Evil laughter)

Comment: @Nolonar Key words: "Hidden and Sneaking."

Comment: Usually, if you accidentally shoot someone in a faction, you can leave the area for a bit and go back to it and they'll be friendly to you again. As far as I know, if you're about to take an action that will make you permanently hated by everyone in a faction, the game makes sure you understand what's about to happen before it lets you take that action.